# Automatic unboxing

Tags: c#, casting, type-conversion, unboxing

I have an array of objects (`object[]`). All the items in this array have the same type (unknown at compile time). I need to convert this array in a typed array, that is, if the items are integers, I want to get an `int[]`.

I've looked into the `Array.ConvertAll` method, but I need to specify a specific type in the template, meaning that I have to get the element type then call `ConvertAll` for each case possible.

I've also looked into the keyword `dynamic` with no more luck (looks like `dynamic[]` is the same as `object[]`).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? How are you going to use the resulting array? Does it really have to be a runtime type (`Type` object), or are generics (`T` type parameter) also okay?

Comment: Just interesting - after runtime conversion `object[]` to `int[]`, what you will do at runtime with your collection? At compile time you will not be able to use your items as `int`s

Comment: I'm using a library with a method like `theMethod(object array)` where array must be an array of a given type (an error is returned in case of `object[]`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to Jon's solution you can do without dynamic and make use of the Array type:

```
public Array Convert(Array a) {
  if (a.GetLength(0) == 0){
    return new int[0];
  }
  var type = a.GetValue(0).GetType();
  var result = Array.CreateInstance(type, a.GetLength(0));
  for (int i = 0; i < a.GetLength(0); i++) {
    result.SetValue(a.GetValue(i), i);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Nice - this is a better solution than mine, although I'd probably use `object[]` as the input, so you can just use `0` and `a.Length` instead of all the lower/upper bounds.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks - I was not aware that actually today you cannot create arrays with a lower bounds other than 0 anymore - they changed that in VB 2003 obviously. I'll update the snippet.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you want something like:

```
dynamic array = Array.CreateInstance(input[0].GetType(), input.Length);
for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
{
    array[i] = (dynamic) input[i];
}
```

Here the `dynamic` just handles the conversion part for you.

Alternatively:

```
public static Array ConvertArray(object[] input)
{
    dynamic sample = input[0]; // Just used for type inference
    return ConvertArrayImpl(sample, input);
}

private static T[] ConvertArrayImpl<T>(T sample, object[] input)
{
    return input.Cast<T>().ToArray();
}
```

You could do make the `ConvertArrayImpl` call with reflection manually of course, instead of using dynamic typing.

Also note that all of these will fail if the input array is empty...

Comment: Your fist version doesn't work, it throws `RuntimeBinderException` with the message "Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'int'.". Changing the loop body to `array[i] = (dynamic)input[i];` fixes that.